# jq split string by a pattern

Tags: json, regex, split, substring, jq

I have a json object with one of field having values for example "**countries-`sapi`-`1.0`**", "**inventory-list-`api`-`1.0-snapshot`**"

Note that the first one has `sapi` and the other one has `api`.

Using `jq`, how can i get countries-sapi  or inventory-list-api I mean whatever is there before the version. the version can be as simple as `1.0` or `1.0.1-snapshot` etc..

Comment: post a valid JSON input data

Comment: Does the version always start with a number and there are no other numbers around or does it always start with number.number (1.0 or 4.7)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to study up on regular expressions (regex); see for example https://regexone.com/ or https://github.com/zeeshanu/learn-regex or dozens of others.

Using jq, in your particular case, you could start with:

```
sub(" *- *[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+.*$"; "")
```

Note that two backslashes are required here because the "from" expression must be (or evaluate to) a valid JSON string.

Answer (score 7):

I got here searching for how to split by regex instead of substring in `jq`, but I found out that you have to give two arguments to the `split` function (where the second argument contains flags for the regex, but it can be just an empty string).

```
$ jq -n '"axxbxxxc"|split("x+";"")'
[
  "a",
  "b",
  "c"
]
```

From the manual:

```
split
    Splits an input string on the separator argument.

        jq 'split(", ")'
           "a, b,c,d, e, "
        => ["a","b,c,d","e",""]

[...]

split(regex; flags)
    For backwards compatibility, split splits on a string, not a regex.
```

Comment: What if the string is stored in a variable and then converted to an array?

Comment: `split` [seems to work fine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78138055/6243352) with one argument.

Answer (score 1):

For input `"countries-sapi-1.0"`, use: `.[] | match( "\\d"; "ig")` which will give you the following output:

```
{
  "offset": 15,
  "length": 1,
  "string": "1",
  "captures": []
}
{
  "offset": 17,
  "length": 1,
  "string": "0",
  "captures": []
}
```

This uses the first object's offset value and tries to slice it from the starting position to the received offset.

Slice from beginning:   `$ jq -c '.[:15]'`

In our case we got 15 as the offset for the first object so we used `:15` for the slice.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, using `match` and assuming versions start with `/-\d+\./`:

```bash
$ echo '["countries-sapi-1.0", "inventory-list-api-1.0-snapshot"]' | \
jq '.[] | match("^.*(?=-\\d+\\.)") | .string'
"countries-sapi"
"inventory-list-api"
```

If you can assume all versions start with `-1.`:

```bash
$ echo '["countries-sapi-1.0", "inventory-list-api-1.0-snapshot"]' | \
jq '.[] | split("-1.") | first'
"countries-sapi"
"inventory-list-api"
```